# Do you need a heroku add-on to send mail via node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, heroku, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer.  I was wondering if it is possible to send e-mails via node without a heroku add-on?

Please educate.  Bless.

Comment: Check out nodemailer https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-mailer. You do not need any addons

Comment: I am using nodemailer -- the app works only when i use it via local host; however, when i upload it to heroku, it no longer works...  I am using gmail as my SMTP account.  Help?

Comment: from the command line, type `heroku logs` add the relevant error (if any) to your question.